# Inject $element in angularjs Controller

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

first, I have read millions of post saying you should not update DOM elements from a Controller in Angular. I know.

When trying to use angular-timer directive (a countdown). I faced some problems, so finally, with the plugin developer help, we did this plunker, which is working and meet my requirements.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CWXnKMbygVDMc8xzshZa?p=preview

However, when moving this code to my app, I got next error when I add the $element to my controller:

```
 `Error: Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element`
```

I have read many posts and I know it can be injected, but I don´t know why it´s not working in my app.

In the other hand, I like to do things right, so I don´t like to implement something that is a bad practice. So, if you have a better approach that works, please let me know.

Comment: Did you remember to register the timer module in your app? (`var app = angular.module('lazy-timer', ['timer']).` and add the `angular-timer.min.js` to your index.html?  `$element` is not found at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ugly parsing DOM with jQuery, and I don't understand why you don't use the timer directive within the `ng-repeat`.

Here's an approach that just adds and extra array to scope for `eleapsedTimers` which are then displayed using `ng-repeat`

```
 $scope.elapsedTimers=[];

$scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (data) {
    /* loop through bookings to find one that just stopped*/
    var now = new Date();
    angular.forEach($scope.bookingsList, function (item) {
        if (!item.elapsed) {
            if (item.booking_date <= now) {                  
                item.elapsed = true;
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.elapsedTimers.push(item)
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="result">
  <div ng-repeat="item in elapsedTimers">ID {{item.id}} elapsed</div>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/bcJGUYeVelgPWIvaDdFV?p=preview)**</kbd>

Note...this will add a new property `elapsed` to the booking object. If this is a problem can create workaround